# Swift video trimming extension error - AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11822

Tags: ios, swift, file, filesystems

I have this code (it's a react native module)

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import CoreMedia

extension FileManager {
  func removeFileIfNecessary(at url: URL) throws {
    guard fileExists(atPath: url.path) else {
      return
    }

    do {
      try removeItem(at: url)
    }
    catch let error {
      throw TrimError("Couldn't remove existing destination file: \(error)")
    }
  }
}

struct TrimError: Error {
  let description: String
  let underlyingError: Error?

  init(_ description: String, underlyingError: Error? = nil) {
    self.description = "TrimVideo: " + description
    self.underlyingError = underlyingError
  }
}

extension AVMutableComposition {
  convenience init(asset: AVAsset) {
    self.init()

    for track in asset.tracks {
      addMutableTrack(withMediaType: track.mediaType, preferredTrackID: track.trackID)
    }
  }

  func trim(timeOffStart: Double) {
    let duration = CMTime(seconds: timeOffStart, preferredTimescale: 1)
    let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: kCMTimeZero, duration: duration)

    for track in tracks {
      track.removeTimeRange(timeRange)
    }

    removeTimeRange(timeRange)
  }
}

extension AVAsset {
  func assetByTrimming(trimStartTime: CMTime,
                       assetDuration: CMTime) throws -> AVAsset {

    let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: trimStartTime, end: assetDuration)

    let composition = AVMutableComposition()

    do {
      for track in tracks {
        let compositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: track.mediaType, preferredTrackID: track.trackID)
        compositionTrack?.preferredTransform = track.preferredTransform
        try compositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: track, at: kCMTimeZero)
      }
    } catch let error {
      throw TrimError("error during composition", underlyingError: error)
    }

    return composition
  }

  func export(to destination: URL) throws {
    guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: self, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough) else {
      throw TrimError("Could not create an export session")
    }

    exportSession.outputURL = destination
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

    let group = DispatchGroup()

    group.enter()

    //        try FileManager.default.removeFileIfNecessary(at: destination)

    exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
      group.leave()
    }

    group.wait()

    if let error = exportSession.error {
      throw TrimError("error during export", underlyingError: error)
    }
  }
}

@objc(VideoTrimmer)
class VideoTrimmer : NSObject {

  func time(_ operation: () throws -> ()) rethrows {
    let start = Date()

    try operation()

    let end = Date().timeIntervalSince(start)
    print(end)
  }

  @objc func trimVideo(_ sourceURL: NSURL,
                       destinationURL: NSURL,
                       duration: Int,
                       preClipDuration: Int,
                       resolver resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
                       rejecter reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {

    do {
      try time {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: sourceURL as URL)
        let assetDuration : CMTime = asset.duration
        let convertedDuration : CMTime = CMTime(seconds: Double(duration), preferredTimescale: 1)
        let preClipConvertedDuration : CMTime = CMTime(seconds: Double(preClipDuration), preferredTimescale: 1)
        var trimStartTime : CMTime
        trimStartTime = CMTimeSubtract(assetDuration, convertedDuration)
        let comparison : Int32 = CMTimeCompare(trimStartTime, preClipConvertedDuration)

        if comparison == 1 {
          trimStartTime = CMTimeSubtract(trimStartTime, preClipConvertedDuration)
        } else {
          trimStartTime = kCMTimeZero
        }
        let trimmedAsset = try asset.assetByTrimming(trimStartTime: trimStartTime, assetDuration: assetDuration)
        try trimmedAsset.export(to: destinationURL as URL)
        resolve("Video trimmed successfully")
      }
    } catch let error {
      reject(" \(error)", nil, error)
    }
  }
}
```

which fails with the following error:
 `TrimError(description: "TrimVideo: error during export", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11822 "Cannot Open" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media format is not supported., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open, NSUnderlyingError=0x1c4250b00 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16976 "(null)"}}))`

I'm passing the following path: 
`assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=E7A2D28D-0FBA-4B40-80CE-B05013D74F28&ext=mov`
also tried without the query `assets-library://asset/asset.mov` but no success.

The file exists because I have it in the camera roll. 
Unfortunately I don't know swift well enough to investigate. 
Any ideas how to make it read the source without complaining about the format?